# How do I configure maven to access maven central if nexus server is down?

Tags: maven, nexus

I would like to setup my build such that it automatically attempts to download an artifact from maven central iff our nexus server is unreachable.  I have the following in settings.xml and I'm not sure how to change it (if even possible).

```
<profiles>
<profile>
 <id>nexus</id>
 <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
 <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
 <repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>central</id>
     <url>http://mynexus</url>
     <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
     <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
   </repository>
 </repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository>
     <id>central</id>
     <url>http://mynexus</url>
     <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
     <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
   </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a repository manager (Nexus included) you need to have a mirrorOf * element defined that will intercept all the repository urls and send them to Nexus for resolution. In Maven2 and 3, the mirrorOf element is not able to be configured in a profile. This means there is no easy way to flip back and forth without changing your settings.

You would need to comment out the mirrors section and then deactivate the Nexus profile to have Maven revert back to standard behavior.

Fortunately though Nexus is very stable and it should never go down.

Comment: +1.
In addition, by "unreachable" I believe he means "when you're out of the office and don't have VPN".

Comment: Thanks, but actually by unreachable I meant something more catastrophic like a networking issue on the node hosting the Nexus server.  I was hoping for an automated failover to maven central in that case so as not to disrupt builds while the nexus issue is diagnosed.

Comment: It sounds nice in theory but in reality it won't help and here's why: Typically your Nexus is proxying much more than just Central, including internal release repositories. You can influence how Nexus locates artifacts by the ordering in the group settings and also by routing rules. If you suddenly drop all of that out of the picture, best case your devs will get different results, most likely case is a whole bunch of the stuff will not be found resulting in build failures.