# Multiple Maven Mirrors for the same repositories

Tags: maven, repository, mirror

As a consultant, I have multiple clients that I'm doing work for.  Each client utilizes their own internal Maven repository that is also set up to mirror Central and other external repositories.  I need to configure my maven installation on my laptop so that when I'm doing work for one client, it utilizes their internal repository for everything.

I had thought I would be able to utilize profiles to handle this, but mirror settings cannot be changed per-profile.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to approach this maven configuration?

Note: A similar question is here: [How do I configure maven to access maven central if nexus server is down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541002/how-do-i-configure-maven-to-access-maven-central-if-nexus-server-is-down), but that question deals with switching between Central coming from a mirror or not.  What I need is for Central (and others) to come from one mirror or a different one based on some property/setting/variable etc.

Comment: I finally found another question that gave me enough insight to answer my own question.  

Reference: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1385744/1481288)

So, what I've done is setup my mirror definition using ${M2_MIRROR} in the URL, and then I can set an environment variable to point to the correct internal repository depending on which client (or internal project) I'm working for.

Comment: +1 very very interesting question ! I'm in the same case, and I was wondering how to deal with such a problem... +1

Answer (score 2):

Create two shell aliases:

```
alias build_at_home="mvn -s $HOME/.m2/home_settings.xml"
alias build_at_work="mvn -s $HOME/.m2/work_settings.xml"
```

The "-s" option is handy for explicitly stating which environment settings file to use.
We use this mechanism on our shared build server to ensure each project build is isolated.

Obviously on windows you could create a set of batch files.

Comment: This seems like a good improvement on the solution of swapping settings files.  So far though, I think I like the environment variable solution the best, where the value is used in the mirror settings of my single settings.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar requirement in my project too. I created two separate `settings.xml` files, named them as `settings_one.xml` and `settings_two.xml` and saved them in the `MAVEN_HOME`. Depending on which file I need, I have a small script (a bat file on windows) which overwrites the existing settings.xml with one of the two settings files.

```
del C:\Users\<username>\.m2\settings.xml
copy C:\Users\<username>\.m2\settings_one.xml C:\Users\tadigotl\.m2\settings.xml
```

Comment: I did not want to have to manage multiple settings files.  I think I found a solution that will work for me.  The clue was in another question that I didn't find when originally researching this.  See my comment in the OP

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution i can suggest is to install git and commit you .m2/settings.xml (of course ignore the repository itself via .gitignore) into git and make appropriate branches for the customers. Change the settings will be done by:

```
git checkout CUSTOMER_BRANCH
```

and furthermore any change is tracked by a SCM.